# Does 'D' language supports 'C' like VLA?

Tags: d

Does 'D' language supports locally-allocated 'C' like variable-length-arrays?

Something like this:

```
void main()
{
    size_t szArr = 3;

    int[szArr] arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, not with runtime variables like that. You'd need to use an alternative:

- `alloca` can allocate runtime sized stack space, just like in C, then you slice it.

  ```
  int[] a = (cast(int*) alloca(size * int.sizeof))[0 .. size];
  ```

That can *not* be abstracted into a function due to how `alloca` works. You could make it a mixin string though.

- You could use a static array, like said in the other answer, then slice it to a size. Something like:

  ```
  int[1024] buffer;
  int[] runtimeSized = size <= buffer.length ? buffer[0 .. size] : (new int[](size);
  ```

Since the buffer is statically sized, you slice it if you can, then make a regular array if not (or you could throw a "Data too big" exception of some sort).

You can abstract this into a nice little struct for easier use if you like.

Remember that storing a reference to stack data after the function returns is invalid, but the compiler won't help much in pointing out where you did it.

Comment: Good answer. Maybe using the `scope` attribute would be reasonable for slices obtained from alloca to check that the slice is not returned.

The current phobos library also has a `std.experimental.algorithm.showcase : StackFront` allocator which can create arrays for you using `makeArray` as far as I understood.